# Footer Div CSS background color Gone in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background

I am working on a Wordpress theme, my footer background color just disappeared and it is appearing accurately even in IE7 but in IE8 there it no bgcolor for my footerwrap div, in all other browser it is working fine........

here is the link 
[Site link with the problem](http://www.acneherbs.org)

Comment: Footer looks the same in IE8 as in Chrome. Also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Provide simple examples demonstrating the problem, and what you have tied to solve it.

Comment: The problem was with the IE8 cache on my PC then, IE8 was loading my old ie8.css file, thanks for making sure that it is looking good on your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doctype claims strict XHTML but your markup is a mishmash of unclosed and invalid tags. It's not surprising you're getting inconsistent results. Try to fix your XHTML or use a HTML doctype and see if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

http://acneherbs.org/wp-content/themes/limegreen/css/ie8.css

lines 257 and 269: `dispaly:block;`

probably meant `display:block;`